# PIL Image conversion - TIFF to JPG and ignoring hidden files and directories during processing

Tags: operating-system, python-imaging-library, jpeg, tiff

> I have written the code and the program outputs the jpegs to the correct directory images/opt/icons. I am also able to run Python 3 and open and check the file type and size characteristics. So I believe it is working properly However, Qwiklabs is not accepting it as successful and i am unable to continue. I have tried the exercise more than 5 times! Even though the code is successful in converting the images and placing them in the correct directory, it does throw errors.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/student-04-feb1d1e1a7a1/./convert.py", line 33, in 
> main()
> File "/home/student-04-feb1d1e1a7a1/./convert.py", line 20, in main
> img = Image.open(inputPath)
> File "/home/student-04-feb1d1e1a7a1/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3218, in open
> fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
> IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/student-04-feb1d1e1a7a1/images/opt'
>
> this is my code: - it is a mix of the Pillow Tutorial and Geek for Geeks code.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

    # Code to apply operations on all the images
    # present in a folder one by one
    # operations such as rotating, cropping,
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageFilter
    import os

    def main():
         # path of the folder containing the raw images
        inPath ="/home/student-04-feb1d1e1a7a1/images/"

        # path of the folder that will contain the modified image
        outPath ="/home/student-04-feb1d1e1a7a1/images/opt/icons/"

        for imagePath in os.listdir(inPath):
            # imagePath contains name of the image
            InputPath = os.path.join(inPath, imagePath)
            img = Image.open(inputPath)
            # inputPath contains the full directory name
            if img.mode != "RGB":
              img = img.convert("RGB")

            fullOutPath = os.path.join(outPath,imagePath)
           # fullOutPath contains the path of the output
            # image that needs to be generated
            img.rotate(90).resize((128,128)).save(fullOutPath, "JPEG", optimize=True, quality=80)
            #print(fullOutPath)

    # Driver Function
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable named `InputPath` with a capital 'I' in the for loop, but you're using `inputPath` with a lowercase 'i' in the subsequent code.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is trying to open itself on the assumption it is an image. Your `os.listdir()` returns everything - not just images.

Maybe try with `glob` module:

```
from glob import glob

for img in glob("*.png"):
    ...
    ...
```

---

By the way, you may also want:

```
im.rotate(90, expand=True)
```